# Add Columns in PowerBI programmatically

Tags: bigdata, powerbi, business-intelligence, dax

I have a List of raw material orders for each Month & each product and want to add columns programmatically to an new Table in PowerBI. In every programming Language i would just write a quick loop, but in this case i don't know how to do it in DAX.

**My Data Format**

```
Month    | Name      | Amount | Price
-----------------------------------
Jan   18 | Product 1 | 1000   | 1200€
March 18 | Product 1 | 1100   | 1400€
Feb   18 | Product 1 | 1000   | 1200€
Jan   18 | Product 2 | 400    | 600€
Feb   18 | Product 2 | 1000   | 1200€
March 18 | Product 2 | 100    | 100€
April 18 | Product 2 | 1000   | 1200€
```

**My desired output Format**

```
Month    | Product 1 | Product 2
---------------------------------
Jan   18 | 1200€     | 600€    
Feb   18 | 1200€     | 1200€
March 18 | 1400€     | 100€
April 18 | 0€        | 1200€
```

Comment: You should be able to load your lists as a table from any datasource (database, file etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the query editor by removing the `Amount` column and pivoting on the `Name` column with `Price` as the values column.

Comment: Thank You for your Answer, however im not sure how to Implement this. its not the raw Query, rather already processed and grouped.

Comment: Edit: nevermind, this really helps. Do you have any tipps, which transformation steps to aplly in powerquery and which in DAX ?

Comment: It's hard to say in general since there is lots of overlap in what each can do. I'm not sure if pivoting and unpivoting are feasible in DAX, so I do those in the query editor.